# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Cookie authentication - sliding expiration not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authentication

I'm trying to get sliding expiration working in ASP.NET Core 3.1 cookie authentication, and whatever I try, the cookie never seems to get refreshed.

My ConfigureServices looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
});
```

and my login process looks like this:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "the user"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
};
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    AllowRefresh = true,
    IsPersistent = true
};
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    authProperties);
```

The cookie correctly comes out with a 1 minute expiry time, but no matter how often I refresh the page after logging in, the cookie is never refreshed to extend the expiry. I've tried with and without HTTPS. I also tried fiddling with various other parameters which seemed like they wouldn't be relevant and sure enough they didn't make any difference.

I can't find any code samples for setting sliding expiration on Core 3.1 without using Identity, but the documentation for Identity here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1 does include a code sample which uses sliding expiration. In desperation I made a new test project with Identity and copied in the code sample:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.Cookie.Name = "YourAppCookieName";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

This didn't work either. So at the moment it looks to me like the sliding expiration is just completely broken in 3.1. Does anyone have any examples where sliding expiration works as expected?

Comment: Have you made certain that the request is being made to the server when you refresh the page? It could be cache thing from the browser. Try to use Postman just to have a better control and understanding of it

Comment: yes it's definitely refreshing from the server

Comment: Is there an authorize attribute to your controller?

Comment: Not in this test, I'm just looking at the expiration date on the cookie in the browser, and at HttpContext.User.Identity on the server (which obviously becomes unauthenticated once the cookie has expired)

Comment: try putting an authorize attribute. Since it's possible that the code does not refresh it since the authorization is not triggered.